# Use Navionics with Flutter

Tags: flutter, leaflet

I wonder if it is possible to use Navionics in Flutter.
I'm currently using flutter_map (the Flutter version of Leaflet) and I would like to add Navionics to it.
I didn't find anything so here I am.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old, but there's no Flutter plugin for Navionics. That being said, Navionics has both an Android and iOS SDK. Theoretically, one could create a Flutter plugin

https://developers.navionics.com/